# Fatal Error with RXTX Java with arduino

Tags: java, arduino

Estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación que comunique Java con Arduino con la librería RXTXcomm.jar que descargué desde [acá](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download)

Ahora puedo listar los puertos seriales habilitados y abrir la conexión con un puerto con las líneas Java:

```
serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().
                        getName(),2000);                    
                // Serial params
                serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,
                        SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                        SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                        SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
```

Pero luego cuando voy a obtener datos del Arduino, lo que obtengo es un error fatal:

```
En el método evento
Antes de readLine()
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ffb7d132462, pid=5049, tid=0x00007ffb57601700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_92-b14) (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.92-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [librxtxSerial.so+0x6462]  read_byte_array+0x52
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/juanpa/developer/LaserLab/hs_err_pid5049.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

El método para leer datos del Arduino es como sigue:

```
/**
 * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
 */
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    String dataLine = "";

    System.out.println("En el metodo evento");

    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Antes de readLine()");
            // Obtiene el texto 
            dataLine = input.readLine();

            System.out.println(dataLine);
            // Actualiza el JTextArea
            //updateLog(dataLine);
            // Guarda en archivo
            System.out.println(dataLine);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
```

El mensaje que está justo antes de la lectura del stream se alcanza a imprimir, pero cuando va a leer `input.readLine()` no se ejecuta y sale el error.

El input stream está definido así:

```
// open the streams
input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
```

Pusé el archivo `librxtxSerial.so` en `<ruta_java>/jre/lib/amd64`.

Estoy usando Fedora 24 64 bits con Oracle Java 8, intenté con openjdk pero tengo el mismo error.

¿Qué puedo probar para resolver esto?

Comment: Hay una línea que te da una posible solución y sobre la que no has comentado nada: `Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again` ¿Has hecho algo al respecto? Según eso es un error de tu arranque de la JVM no de tu código.

Comment: Ejecuté el comando ulimit -c unlimited antes de correr el programa y tengo el mismo error.

Comment: Si te da el mismo error entonces debes poner una pregunta para solucionar ese problema en otro sitio. Aquí se ayuda con problemas de programación. El mensaje te indica que el error está en código nativo fuera de la JVM.

Comment: Gracais Awes0meM4n por la ayuda. Por si es relevante ahora, intenté con java6 de 32 bits y la comunicación funciona sin lanzar el error fatal.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve el mismo problema (programando en Linux Kali amd64), pero al momento de exportar el archivo y ejecutarlo desde el terminar, la interrupción producida por la llegada de datos y la lectura del `inputStream` funcionan perfectamente.

Otra cosa importante, es que si un `EventListener` a mi puerto y en mi caso en particular, es necesario agregar un `delay (thread.sleep())` inmediatamente después del método que atiende el evento, para que el programa "tenga tiempo" de mostrar la trama que recibió en el terminal `(System.out.println())`, de lo contrario no imprime nada.

Ojala les sea de ayuda.
Saludos.

Comment: Hola Dev.Joel.
Gracias por el aporte, desde el Arduino hice un delay al enviar datos de lo contrarió perdía datos.